# reset emberjs model in form

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms, ember.js

I have a route that displays a list of posts and also a form for creating a new post.

posts_route.js.coffee:

```
Fortchan12.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend                                                                                   
  model: ->                                                                                                                   
    Ember.RSVP.hash                                                                                                       
      posts: @get('store').findAll 'post'                                                                                    
      newPost: @get('store').createRecord 'post' 

  actions:                                                                                                                 
    create: (post) ->                  
      post.setProperties                                                                                               
        name: this.controller.get('name')                                                                              
        body: this.controller.get('body')                                                                              
        photo: this.controller.get('photo')                                                                                                                                                              
      post.save()
```

and here is the handlebars template:

```
<h2>make a new post</h2>                                                                                                   
<form {{action 'create' newPost on="submit"}}>                                                                             
  {{#if isSaving}}                                                                                                         
    <p>saving post...</p>                                                                                                  
  {{/if}}                                                                                                                  
  <p>{{input type="text" value=name}}</p>                                                                                  
  <p>{{textarea value=body}}</p>                                                                                           
  <button type="submit">Create</button>                                                                                    
</form>                                                                                                                    

<h2>posts</h2>                                                                                                             
{{#each posts}}                                                                                                            
  {{name}} says                                                                                                            
  {{body}}                                                                                                                 
  {{created_at}}                                                                                                             {{#link-to 'post' this}}                                                                                                 
    {{id}}                                                                                                                   {{/link-to}}                                                                                                             
  <br />
```

This seems to work fine, but I want to clear out the form after it is submitted and saved so I can make another post. I can do this in the create action in the route to clear out the form (although it doesn't seem to clear out the file input field):

```
    self.controller.setProperties({name: '', body: '', photo: ''})
```

but that doesn't seem to 'reset' the model, when I submit the form again its trying to PUT to /posts/:id, instead of POST to /posts:

```
PUT http://0.0.0.0:3000/posts/70 404 (Not Found)
```

I'm not exactly sure what I am supposed to do, I've read that using setupController is an option but I'm not sure how to do that with using multiple models in my route like I am.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to create a new record as well, the page still has a reference to the other record, which you saved, and now that record has an id, which is why its trying to update that record (excuse the javascript).

```
actions:                                                                                                                 
 create: (post) ->         
  self = @                                                                                                                                                           
  post.save().then(function(){
    self.set('controller.newPost', self.get('store').createRecord('post'));
  });
```

Psuedo code mix for using all

```
model: function(){
  return Ember.RSVP.hash({                                                                                                       
      posts: @get('store').findAll 'post',                                                                                  
      newPost: @get('store').createRecord 'post'
  }); 
},
setupController: function(controller, model){
  controller.set('posts', this.get('store').all('post'));
  controller.set('newPost', model.newPost);
}
```

reversed computed property

on the controller

```
reverseProperty: function(){
   this.get('posts').sortBy('foo').toArray().reverse();
}.property('posts.[]')
```

Comment: Thanks that seems to have worked. Although I can create a new post now, the posts don't update for some reason. Do I need to add something like this: self.controller.set('posts', self.get('store').findAll('post'))

Comment: Do I do this in the controller?

Comment: The route is a perfectly acceptable place to do it.  Additionally you could probably just use the `all` filter instead of calling `findAll` again, I'll toss up an example

Comment: findAll will make another call to the server (which you may be cool with), but the all filter is live, aka as you add new records it updates).

Comment: Ah they are! But I return my records with a default scope of updated_at DESC, so it puts the new posts at the bottom....I'm guessin g the filter can do reversing or sorting somehow?

Comment: You can create a computed property watching the `posts` property, and sort it then reverse it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried resetting the model like this?

```
@controller.set('content', @get('store').createRecord('post'))
```

Comment: thanks nik i think this is what i want except i need to set 'newPost' instead of 'content' like kingpin2k said

Comment: I didn't realize you were in the route, you'll have to do it to the controller